# Я скрываю toolbar при скролле, как сделать так, что бы при смене фрагмента toolbar динамически возвращался на место

Tags: android, android-fragment, recyclerview, android-toolbar, bottom-navigation-view

У меня есть toolbar который скрывается при скролле:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolbarLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:elevation="0dp">

                <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap">
                        <TextView
                            android:text="@string/app_name"
                            android:textSize="26sp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_margin="4dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:defaultNavHost="true"
                app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

И если я проскроллил вверх(toolbar скрылся), а потом открываю другой фрагмент(в котором нет возможности скроллить) из bottomNavigationView, то toolbar остается скрытым.
Вопрос: как сделать так, что бы при открытии другого фрагмента, toolbar автоматически съезжал вниз

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
AppBarLayout toolbarLayout = findViewById(R.id.toolbarLayout);
toolbarLayout.setExpanded(true, true);
```

Comment: никакой реакции

Comment: @Shamil попробуй задать id для CollapsingToolbarLayout и вызвать 
 `сollapsingToolbarLayout.animate().translationY(0).start();`

Comment: Я попробовал добавить в activity_main FloatingActionBar и при нажатии на нее выполнять этот код toolbarLayout.setExpanded(true, true). В таком случае все работает. Но как реализовать, что бы при смене экрана это происходило. Для навигации я использую Navigation Components

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо тебе добрый человек

Comment: Рад был помочь, тёзка)

Answer (score 1):

Я из фрагмента вызвал этот код

AppBarLayout toolbarLayout = findViewById(R.id.toolbarLayout);
toolbarLayout.setExpanded(true, true);

через getActivity()